# Как с помощью метода scrollToItemAtIndexPath класса UICollectionView пролистать до нужной страницы?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Есть объект класса `UICollectionView`, у которого свойство `pagingEnabled` имеет значение `true`. Каждая страница (если можно так говорить) данного объекта представлена одной секцией из его источника данных. После перезапуска приложения мне нужно перелистывать данный `UICollectionView` на ранее просматриваемую страницу, однако вызывая `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` с разными параметрами типа `UICollectionViewScrollPosition` я получаю странную картинку - заданная ячейка оказывается посреди страницы либо в совсем непонятном месте, в любом случае получается так, как будто бы листал не человек, а само устройство. Мне же нужно перелистать так, чтобы в итоге всё было на экране так, как будто сам пользователь успел самостоятельно открыть ранее просматриваемую страницу. Подойдёт любое решение, необязательно через `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`, надеюсь понятно чего я хочу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих поисков в интернете я смог найти решение лишь через метод `setContentOffset:animated:`. Данный метод устанавливает смещение для всего, что отображается в объекте класса `UICollectionView`. Проще говоря, можно использовать данный код:

```
NSInteger pageNumber = 10; // Номер ранее выбранной страницы
[collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width * pageNumber, 0) animated:NO];
```